# Change the primary and secondary group of a user using a script

Tags: linux, bash

So what I am trying to do is run a script, that can only be run from Root, and it creates new usernames and passwords. The script checks to see if that username and password already exist, and if it does, it will not create the new username. All of that works fine, but now, if a new user is created, I want to be able to add this new user to a group.

For example, lets say I want the primary group to be alpha and the secondary group to be beta. How would I be able to:

1. Set a user to just the primary group
2. Set a user to primary and secondary group
3. Set a user to only the secondary group

The following is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Creating a script that creates a new user and password, runs in Root, accessible # in any shell, ADD USER TO SPECIFIC GROUPS NOW (itar and bfe already created)

ROOT_UID=0      #Root has $UID 0
SUCCESS=0
E_USEREXISTS=70
E_NOTROOT=65        #Not root

#Run as root, and this checks to see if the creater is in root. If not, will not run
if [ "$UID" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ]; then
    echo "Sorry must be in root to run this script"
    exit $E_NOTROOT
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
username=$1
passwd=$2

grep -q "$username" /etc/passwd

#Checking if the username and password already exists 
if [ $? -eq $SUCCESS ]; then
    echo "User $username already exists"
    echo "Please choose another username"
    exit $E_USEREXISTS 
fi

#Creating the new username and the new password:
    useradd $username -d /home/$username -m ;
    echo $passwd | passwd $username --stdin;
    echo "The new user account is setup"

#Adding the user to group bfe or itar
echo "Which group will this user be in?"
read x more

#If the person does not give the correct number of arguments 
else
    echo "This program needs 2 arguments and you have given $#"
    echo "You have to call the script and provide a username and password"


#if [ \"$x\" -eq "bfe" ]; then #echo "First word was \"$x\""
#   usermod -g bfe $username
#if [ \"$x\" -eq "itar" ]; then 
#   usermod -g itar $username 

fi

exit 0
```

Any help would be appreciated! Still learning the ropes so please take it easy on me.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not csh (and *also* not bash). What is the csh tag doing here?

Comment: BTW, `grep -q "$username" /etc/passwd` is going to give you false positives -- let's say you have a user `cduffy` and you're creating a user `duffy`; grepping for `duffy` will match `cduffy`. Consider `if gentent passwd "$username" >/dev/null; then ...` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I included csh because this script is to run in both bash and csh. I didn't make that clear

Comment: That's almost impossible. bash is a superset of the POSIX sh standard; csh is from a completely different family that isn't compatible with `/bin/sh` at all. *Why* do you need compatibility with csh? (Note that users can start a script that runs with bash or /bin/sh *from* csh without *interpreting the script with csh*, which is the part that requires it to be written using an entirely different syntax).

Comment: ...for example, `username=$1` isn't a valid variable assignment in csh. It's a *completely* different syntax.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest running this as a whole through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. (Also, in general, use `if foo; then ...` where possible instead of `foo; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...` -- the former is more robust against future changes in the code modifying exit status inadvertently, ie. via adding extra logging).

Comment: I see what you mean, well I was supposed to have this script run in csh, and when I switch shells to run it, it runs in both bash and csh. And thank you for that suggestion, I will test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-G` option for `useradd`.

```
-G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
      A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of.Each 
      group is separated from the next by a comma, with no intervening
      whitespace. 
      The groups are subject to the same restrictions 
      as the group given with the -g option. 
      The default is for the user to belong only
      to the initial group.
```

Then rearrange part of your script, something like this

```
#Adding the user to group bfe or itar
echo "Which group will this user be in?"
read x

# Check if group exists
grep -q "$x" /etc/group || echo "Group doesn't exist"

#Creating the new username and the new password:
useradd "$username" -d "/home/$username" -m -G "$x" ;
echo "$passwd" | passwd "$username" --stdin;
echo "The new user account is setup"
```

You can use `-G` to assign more than one group to the user.

Comment: Okay thank you! I just have a small question, so I did that and its working. But is there a way to also allow them to add themselves to a second group? Using this script? Cause I want the option to add them to a primary group, as this example you provided does, but what about being able to add them into a secondary group?

Comment: There really should be more quotes here -- ie. `useradd "$username" -d "/home/$username"`. Granted, users shouldn't specify names containing spaces, but if they do, we want well-behaved sensible error messages, not ones that result from parsing different pieces of the name as different arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Edited.

Comment: @Candy You can use `-G` to assign multiple groups to the same user. You need to change the stdin section accordingly.